# How To Programmatically Execute "Clear File Explorer History"

Tags: c#, windows

I'm currently creating a WPF application, and like to add as a small side feature the ability to ***clear*** the windows file explorer history.

If one were to manually do this operation, it is possible via the file menu within a file explorer window,
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQxn3.png).

My goal is pretty much to programmatically execute the same action as this button does, but I've been unable to find what executable or user32.dll method is behind this operation (if it exists), and been also unsuccessful on finding the full logic behind it (namely, finding what folder and files it targets), to replicate it.

Can you help me?

Comment: Check out _MS UI Automation_.  Though originally designed for testing apps, it can be used as a general purpose remote-control mechanism

Comment: See [SHAddToRecentDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shaddtorecentdocs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment by dxiv suggested, you can achieve this via the following:

```cs
enum ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags
{
   Pidl = 0x001,
   Path = 0x002,
   PathW = 0x003
}

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void SHAddToRecentDocs(ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags flag, string path);

// How To Clear Everything
SHAddToRecentDocs(ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags.Pidl, null);
```